# Play GIF in Userform WebBrowser While Performing Calculations

Tags: excel, vba, userform

super appreciate any help in advance. I want to display a web-based GIF via url in a userform webbrowser. I want the gif animation to play WHILE the workbook is doing calculations. Two problems.

1. Main problem, userform loads and displays only the very first frame of the GIF while the calculations execute. Once the calculations are complete, then the GIF starts playing as desired. I want these things to occur simultaneously.
2. Userform doesn't go away despite asking to Unload it after the calculations complete.

**Userform1 Code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.WebBrowser1
        .Navigate "https://media.tenor.com/hKsgsuQ5N8MAAAAC/cymbals-monkey-brain.gif"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    WebBrowser1.Document.body.Scroll = "No"
End Sub
```

**Button Code**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    With New UserForm1
        .Label1.Caption = "Calculate while GIF plays"
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
    
    DoEvents
    
    For ii = 1 To 200
        Calculate
    Next ii
    
    Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The GIF displays properly for me.
2. The code is unloading the default UserForm1 not the instance that is being shown.

---

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Form As New UserForm1
    With Form
        .Label1.Caption = "Calculate while GIF plays"
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
    
    For ii = 1 To 200
        Calculate
        DoEvents
    Next ii
    
    Unload Form
End Sub
```